# Color the individuals of a R PCoA plot by groups

Tags: r, plot, vegan, mds

Should be a simple question, but I haven't found exactly how to do it so far.

I have a matrix as follow:

```
sample var1 var2 var3 etc.
1      5    7    3     1
2      0    1    6     8
3      7    6    8     9
4      5    3    2     4
```

I performed a PCoA using Vegan and plotted the results. Now my problem is that I want to color the samples according to a pre-defined group:

```
group sample
1     1
1     2
2     3
2     4
```

How can I import the groups and then plot the points colored according to the group tey belong to? It looks simple but I have been scratching my head over this.

Thanks!
Seb

Answer (score 1):

You said you used **vegan** PCoA which I assume to mean `wcmdscale` function. The default `vegan::wcmdscale` only returns a scores matrix similarly as standard `stats::cmdscale`, but if you added some special arguments (such as `eig = TRUE`) you get a full `wcmdscale` result object with dedicated `plot` and `points` methods and you can do:

`plot(<pcoa-result>, type="n") # no reproducible example: edit like needed
points(<pcoa-result>, col = group) # no reproducible example: group must be visible`

If  you have a modern **vegan** (2.5.x) the following also works:

`library(magrittr)
plot(<full-pcoa-result>, type = "n") %>% points("sites", col = group)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but it still doesn't work. Here is the script I used:

distmatrix <- vegdist(dataset[, 2:63],method='bray', na.rm=T)
Ordination.model1 <- cmdscale(distmatrix, k=2, eig=T, add=F) 
rownames(Ordination.model1$points) <- rownames(dataset)
plot(scores(Ordination.model1, display='sites', choices=c(1,2), col = 
dataset$Col.grp))
I am a bit puzzled, I used a similar script previously to color groups (not from vegan output though) and it worked. I can't see what is not working there...

Comment: First thing: do **not** use `plot(scores())` but just `plot`! There is no `plot.scores()` function, and you must at least set `asp=1` (for equal aspect ratio) if you use `plot(scores())`. Second thing: now you give your graphical arguments to the `scores()` function (that you should not use), and the `scores` function does no graphics, but wastes these arguments. You should give these arguments to `plot` **without** using `scores()`. Where did you get the idea of using `scores()`? Certainly not from **vegan** documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Finally figured it out by building the graph in sequence from the metaMDS function, the `points` variable and a separate vector of colors. It goes something like that: `data.mds <- metaMDS(my.data)` then `col.vect <- c("green", "red")` then `plot(data.mds, type = "n")` then `with(data.grp, points(data.mds, display = "sites", col = col.vect[Groups], bg = col.vect[Groups])`